# iphone app that formats texts like a word processor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

Sorry for such a general questions, but I'm wondering if (and how) it is possible to write an iPhone App which formats a txt file on different pages - just like Microsoft Word would do in layout mode if you open a new document and paste a txt file.

In other words, I don't want to use an UITextView which is endless. All I need is an editor which formats text on different pages.

Is there an easy way or would I need to program everything by myself? I.e. cut txt files in different pieces and handle the user input accordingly (e.g. if he pastes something, if he deletes something, if he reaches the end of the page, etc. etc.).

I guess this would be quite trivial on Mac OS X (I just had a look at their docs of how to create a simple text editor) but I get the feeling that this is nearly impossible on the iPhone.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem to split one large text into something that looks like a layout view in Ms Word. The problem appears when you consider editing the text. One way you can go about it is to always keep full tekst in one placeholder and allow user to edit that placeholder instead of particular "pages". Then after the edit is finished you split the text into appropriate pages. If you would want to edit each page separately you would have to handle adjustment of pages yourself which is a pain, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

For display you can use `-[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:]` to measure your text. From there you need to manually split the text into chunks that fit your page size.

If the text is to be editable, then you need to also implement the `UITextInput` protocol, and should probably use Core Text to do your text drawing. This can be summed up as: allot of work.