# How to create .doc file or word processor in iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, openxml

I am looking for *word file processing* in IOS application. I digging many things on google from that i found word file is based on [OOXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx). It`s possible for iOS to follow this format.Then please refer me if anyone have idea.

Then i tried to found another way to changes styles of .doc file. and i found, we can perform such thing in UIWebView using [JavaScripts](http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/rich-text-editing-sample-project/) on .html file. But still not get how to store this .html file in .doc.

if anyone have idea regarding word-processor then guide me how it`s possible in objective C any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873583/iphone-app-that-formats-texts-like-a-word-processor

Comment: but i have to perform all styling functionality like MS-Word. not only add text. if you work on it and have any good reference then tell me.

Answer (score 6):

Try the [libopc](http://libopc.codeplex.com) open source library, which according to their website is a:

- ISO/IEC 29500 standard conformant,
- cross-platform,
- open source,
- standard C99-based

implementation of Part II (OPC) and Part III (MCE) of the ISO/IEC 29500 specification (OOXML).

Comment: is it possible to use this for creating new word documents in an iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString*)generate_Doc:(Projects *)project AndCompanyInformation:(CompanyInfo*)companyInfo;
{


    NSDateFormatter *date_formater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [date_formater setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm"];
    [date_formater setTimeZone:[DefaultDataManager AppTimeZone]];
    NSDate *now = [DefaultDataManager AppCurrentTime];

    NSString *fileName =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@.doc",project.title,project.reference,[date_formater stringFromDate:now]];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *docFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];





NSData *data = [docString dataFromRange:(NSRange){0, [docString length]} documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} error:NULL];
    [data writeToFile:docFileName atomically:YES];

 return docFileName;
}
```