# Creating *.docx (and maybe *.doc ?) documents in the fly?

Tags: iphone, c++, c, ios, xml

I want to create some simple documents (basically text, footer, maybe some titles, etc) programatically.

The problem is that I am not using .NET. I am in iOS so I cannot use the [official SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124)

Is there any library in C, C++, or maybe Obj-C that could help?
I know that *.docx is XML so I should be able to write it myself but I would rather not re-invent the wheel if there is something handy out there.

Comment: Take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145573/creating-opening-and-printing-a-word-file-from-c

Comment: and.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835152/how-to-create-doc-file-or-word-processor-in-ios-application

Comment: .docX .xmlX are actually a zip archive, not a XML file.

Comment: @Nyx0uf, a .docx is both - a collection of XML and image files wrapped up in a ZIP.

Comment: @moritz if you put your comment as an answer I will make you the winner :) Apparently libOPC is what I am looking for.

Comment: it's still just a comment, you're welcome though :-)

Comment: @nacho4d: With your permission, I can post an answer with due attributions (moritz's comment and jason answer post), of course the best option is that you answer and accept your own question: Your post is a resolved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @moritz (in the comments) I found this question that suggest [libopc](https://libopc.codeplex.com) which is what I was looking for.
[How to create .doc file or word processor in iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835152/how-to-create-doc-file-or-word-processor-in-ios-application)

Answer (score 1):

1. Perhaps you should consider exporting to RTF-format. MS Word (all versions) can read RTF-files. Maybe it will be enough for your purposes.
2. **doc**-files actually are [*docfiles*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319/Structured-Storage-The-DocFile) (structured storage files) with unopened structure. I do not familiar with iOS, but in windows with installed Word you can use API, that Word provides, to generate documents.
3. **docx**-files are zipped set of files and folders. They have a public **OpenXML** format. It is possible to read the specification of OpenXML or use one of free libraries to generate the required document. However, it looks that you don't need to do it for your purposes. As I understand it, the structure of your document is known in advance. So, you can create a sample of your document. Then unzip created docx-file. Locate where the text of your document stored. Try to change text and then zip files and folder to other docx-file. If you did everything correctly you get a new file with your new text. Therefore, you will know how to programmatically generate desired documents.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok for your app to use a service over the net, then a cloud service like that provided by Docmosis will produce doc files based on templates that you upload separately.  They can be streamed back to your app, emailed off etc.  This approach can save you a lot of dev time but it's not a free service.  I don't think it does docX, but it does pdf, odt and some other formats.