# Can we Add Textfields in word file by code?

Tags: ios, iphone, ms-word

I want to add Textfields in word file by code.. is that possible in iphone?

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense. Care to elaborate?

Comment: By "word file", do you mean a Microsoft Word Document?

Comment: Gerald Kaszuba - i want to create a custom microsoft word file by coding

Comment: @kanwar : That would be very helpful of entire world. There is no such API for reading and writing xls, xlsx, so I guess no .doc or .docx will be there.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya- like we create a word file and add content into word file.. then i think there might be way to create custom files.. the diffrence will be only in how and what content to be passed to file in word document.. is in it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could dig up: [How to create .doc file or word processor in iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835152/how-to-create-doc-file-or-word-processor-in-ios-application)

It's not most encouraging answer, but it's a starting point.

The library is located at http://libopc.codeplex.com/